# Javascript: How to create a window/dropdown menu based on an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint

**Situation:** I have a Sharepoint list. I have an object filled with few string elements. I have an event when this function should trigger.

**What I desire:** I would like to create a window or dropdown menu or whatever where the user can click on the element to select one.

**Problem:** I can't edit the HTML directly (Sharepoint autogenerated), so what I can do is add some script in the Script editor. Any option to create a menu where the user can choose from the object is fine. (Probably creating a new window and disable to click other part of the site during it opened would be the easliest method, but I am not sure).

May I ask you to show me an example how to create it?

```
//some code to generate the window/dropdown/ect here
    function getData(info) //info is the object
        {
          for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
          {
          //I should add the object elements to the window/dropdown/ect here
          }
        }
```

Comment: info: {"test1","test2","test3","test4","test5"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First choose where you want to create the dropdown in your HTML. For example, imagine you have a `div` where you want to add it...

```
<div id="yourplace">
</div>
```

... so first you have to create the `select` element with an `id`. After that, you can loop through the info object, create the `option` element for each value and add it to the created element.

In this case you can't use `for` because you're working with an object, but you can use the jquery `$.each()` function, so you could do something like this...

```
var myInfo = { 0: "test1",
               1: "test2",
               2: "test3",
               3: "test4",
               4: "test5" }; 

$('div#yourplace').append('<select id="infodropdown"></select>');

function getData(info) {

    var myOptions = [];
    $.each(info,function(index,value) {
        myOptions.push('<option value="'+value+'">'+value+'</option>');
    });

    $('select#infodropdown').html(myOptions);
}

getData(myInfo);
```

Here you have a test fiddle... https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/16ot7w0b/

I hope it helps

Comment: Good to hear! Have a nice day and happy coding!